# Delphi: copy object contents into another instance

Tags: delphi

What's the fastest way to copy the contents of an object with simple fields (strings, integers, booleans) into another instance?

```
Type TMyClass = packed class
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: Integer;
end;

Var z,x: TMyClass;
begin
  z := TMyClass.Create;
  x := TMyClass.Create;
  z.a := 'test';
  z.c := 20;

  // copy z into x

  caption := x.a;
  x.free;
  z.free;
```

Comment: What is a packed class?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I was confused too, that's a thing for records, but apparently, Delphi allows you to use it on classes - although has zero effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TPersistent` is designed with this in mind, which is also the base class of `TComponent`. More specifically, its `Assign` method, which you'd be responsible to override to copy.

For example...

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FSomething: String;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  S: TMyClass;
begin
  if Source is TMyClass then begin
    S:= TMyClass(Source);
    FSomething:= S.FSomething;

    //and everything else

  end else
    inherited; //Will fail on purpose
end;
```

Note: Above code is quick and untested, but that's the idea.

Then, you could make a copy like...

```
MyNewInstance.Assign(MyOldInstance);
```

Comment: I was thinking more something like directly copying/writing on the memory of the objects.

Comment: @hikari Not necessarily, no. Records work that way. But when it comes to objects, it's more involved. You could always roll out your own equivalent method like what I described, but you'd still need to explicitly do the assignments somewhere.

Comment: @hikari: That's not possible in general. Think of reference type members, such as strings, dynamic arrays, pointers to dynamically allocated memory, etc. You need to write your own deep-copy routine. And as Jerry points out, the `Assign` method is a good choice.

Comment: Regarding the above example, however, combining `is` and `as` is not necessary. After the `is` test, you can use simple `TMyClass(Source)` casts -- otherwise you perform the same test twice (or 21 times, if you have 20 members).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Indeed, there are neater ways to do it, I slapped that together quickly. I do recall a few years back a debate between using `(source as TMyClass)` and `TMyClass(Source)`. Using `as` is a bit more clear to developers who might not be familiar/comfortable yet with casting/inheritance etc. But I do tend to use `TMyClass(Source)`, and actually I typically declare a variable and assign it just once. But that's a long stretch to make a minimal answer.

Comment: @Andreas I understand that, but in this specific case with only strings, integers, booleans, shouldn't it be possible to copy the object contents memory as if it was a record? or maybe put all those variables into a record inside the class, then copy over the record somehow

Comment: @hikari: Yes, if you have a record member, that can be copied just like any other record. String members in the record will be copied with the usual copy-on-write semantics, so it will work well. But, beware of the downside of having a record *property* in a class: you cannot assign values to its members.

Comment: But copying the record should be faster than manually copying each variable. The new instance can even be read-only, I don't need to modify the contents after the copy. I'm looking for the fastest way to accomplish this

Comment: @hikari Then use records instead of objects, as they are lighter weight and behave the way you want.

Comment: I was doing that then changed to a class for convenience and other reasons

Comment: To be clear, strings are pointers, even when they are fields of records. If a record contains a string, the compiler arranges the copy but it's not copying a block of memory. It will have little performance difference, if at all, then manually assigning fields.

Comment: @hikari Look at it this way - if this were possible, then the RTL would be using that method instead of the widespread `Assign` method. Such an object *could* potentially have much more complex classes, such as lists, and other nested objects. Imagine trying to copy all that automagically.